# How to create a mini-game?

Tags: directx, direct3d, game-engine

I'am wondering how to create a mini-game like "diner dash" or like "big fish games". I want my game to be 2D but it looks like 3D. See this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [topxgames.com](http://www.topxgames.com/bigfish/diner-dash-flo-through-time/screen1.jpg))</sub>

If you know some good game-engine to create like those games, please let me know.

Comment: You may want to try this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like for you Unity3D would be good. Its a easy to use game-engine that uses c# for its scripts..

http://unity3d.com/

It can be used to make PC, Mac, XBOX, WII, PS3, iPhone & Android games.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java to create 2d or 3d games like  "diner dash" or like "big fish games" .
take a look here http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/game/

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the ever popular Unreal engine or Directx, or even the XNA framework for .NET. Just to name a few. For web based you can try unity 3d or if you want to keep it simple maybe flash will work for you. There's too many choices and it all depends on your preference.